# Why is DOMDocument not working with WAMP server?

Tags: php, wamp, domdocument

I’m using `DOMDocument` to retrieve several bits of text from a webpage and place them into an array. The same code works on another server, yet doesn’t on mine. I get `Trying to get property of non-object` for each iteration of the `while` loop and the array remains empty at the end.

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://sugarkettle.site44.com/catering.html");
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();

$meatPrices = array();

function fillArrayFromDOM($array,$type) {
    global $doc;
    $i = 0;
    $label = 1;
    $array = array();
    while ($label <= 15):
      $array[$i] = $doc->getElementById($type.$label)->textContent;
      $i++;
      $label++;
    endwhile;
    return $array;
}

fillArrayFromDOM($meatPrices,"meat");
echo var_dump($meatPrices);
```

Here’s a link to it working:
http://www.evintr.com/willtest.php

He’s running a GoDaddy server and I have a local WAMP (2.2) server. Any configuration options I can provide that might explain why this is happening? Or does the problem have nothing to do with my server config?

Any help much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

### Update 1 - 11/16/12

On my server, I've tested `$meatPrices[1] = $doc->getElementById('meat1')->textContent;` and it works. For whatever reason, inside the `while` loop the same expression (except with variables in the `getElementById` parameters) tosses an error: `Trying to get property of non-object`.

### Update 2 - 11/17/12

My WAMP server is running PHP version **5.3.13**.
My friend's server is running PHP version **5.3.6**.

Comment: have you checked if `$html` contains anything on the bad server? your code simply assumes that you got the desired html and the tags/ids you want exist, without ever checking if that's really the case. you should **NEVER** assume success when you're using remotely-fetched data.

Comment: Yes, I omitted a bit of test code that printed the exact text I was aiming to retrieve. The code will work outside a function, but not within for some reason. I'll update my question to reflect this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with adding `allow_url_fopen=on` in your PHP configuration file (`php.ini`). Save it and restart Apache; it should work...

**EDIT:**
Check also if you have extension `php_openssl.dll` enabled (`extension=php_openssl.dll` in your `php.ini` file). Again, restart of Apache would be required.

**EDIT:**

It depends on PHP version you have but here are two potential solutions:

1. replace line `fillArrayFromDOM($meatPrices,"meat");` with
   `$meatPrices = fillArrayFromDOM($meatPrices,"meat")`; You can also
   change your function to remove necessary $meatPrices parameter).

or

1. replace line `function fillArrayFromDOM($array,$type) {` with `function fillArrayFromDOM(&$array,$type) { //note new character &; it will keep reference to $array variable so it could be changeable;` you can also remove line: `$array = array();`

Both should work; I am in rush have no time to wait on your comment response. Let us know what you get...

Comment: openssl isn't necessary, since the url OP is fetching from isn't https.

Comment: @salih0vicX I went ahead and gave it a shot. Turns out `php.ini` already had `allow_url_fopen = on`. Even after activating the `php_openssl.dll` extension and restarting Apache, I still get the same error. I appreciate your suggestion, thanks anyway!

Comment: It is than this line: `$array[$i] = $doc->getElementById($type.$label)->textContent;` returning error (ID not found...). It will return the same error as you mentioned on any server. The reason it seems to work on http://www.evintr.com/willtest.php is because of `error_reporting` setup (http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php). If you add for example: `error_reporting(0)` it won't throw you that notice on local server either.

Comment: I added `error_reporting(0);` to the top of the script and the errors no longer appear, but the array is still empty at the end, which doesn't constitute a working script for me. Since both my server and my friend's are running the precise same code, wouldn't the error reporting be the same for both environments?

Comment: What is your PHP version? It is not related to the error_reporting() directive...

Comment: My PHP version is 5.3.13. My friend's PHP version is 5.3.6. Is there anything I should look up in `phpinfo(0);`?

Comment: Your latest update worked! I simply added `&` in front of the `$meatPrices` in `function fillArrayFromDOM(&$array,$type) {`. Errors are still being tossed, but I can simply suppress them with `error_reporting` when I've debugged the final script. Thank you very much @salih0vicX, I really appreciate your effort in helping me.